# Doctrine DBAL setParameter() with array value

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, dbal

I'm using doctrine DBAL and have some problem with SQL query as result of a queryBuilder.

```
$builder = $this->getConnection()->getQueryBuilder();
$builder->select(['id','name','type'])
         ->from('table')
         ->where('id='.(int)$value)
         ->setMaxResults(1);
$builder->andWhere($builder->expr()->in('type', ['first','second']));

echo(builder->getSQL());

$data = $builder->execute()->fetchRow();
```

And get SQL

```
SELECT id, name, type FROM table WHERE (id=149) AND (type IN (first,second)) LIMIT 1
```

And this is the problem, I need that (type IN (first,second)) was encoded as strings like (type IN ('first','second'))

How to do that with query builder in the right way?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try with

```
$builder->andWhere('type IN (:string)');
$builder->setParameter('string', ['first','second'], \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Thank you, the second variant with \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY works great for me!

Comment: First case does not work, because dbal don't wraps strings in array without parameter type.

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev you are right but I wasn't able to test it so I've wrote an answer by trying to change array definiton and specifying parameter type

Comment: Hopefully the yet-to-be-finished [SO Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) will help fill these kinds of holes. It took me six hours of googling to find this answer.

Comment: `\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STRING_ARRAY` is deprecated in newer versions. Use `\Doctrine\DBAL\ArrayParameterType::STRING` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The array parameters used above are deprecated

New way is

```
\Doctrine\DBAL\ArrayParameterType:INTEGER
\Doctrine\DBAL\ArrayParameterType:STRING
\Doctrine\DBAL\ArrayParameterType:ASCII
\Doctrine\DBAL\ArrayParameterType:BINARY
```

```php
$builder->setParameter('type', ['foo','bar'], \Doctrine\DBAL\ArrayParameterType:STRING)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$builder
    ->andWhere($builder->expr()->in('type', ':types'))
    ->setParameter(':types', ['first','second'], \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);
```