# Why Doctrine Param_str_array conversion is not working as expected?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to bind an array of strings into the where-in condition. I used the parameters conversions constants also. But it seems to be not working.

Following one is my query.

```
$buQuery = "SELECT bu.ID, bu.BUSINESS_NAME FROM business as bu WHERE bu.ID IN (:business)";

$buStmt = self::getConnection($this->entityManager)->prepare($buQuery);

$buStmt->bindValue("business", $business, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);

$buStmt->execute();

$responseData = $buStmt->fetch();

return $responseData;
```

and the array I'm passing for the in condition is (I have printed this array from the parameters list and copied it over here.)

```
$business = Array ( 0 => 'mobile', 1 => 'iot' );
```

The error the doctrine throws me is:

> An Exception was thrown while handling: An exception occurred while executing SELECT bu.ID, bu.BUSINESS_NAME FROM business as bu WHERE bu.ID IN (:business) with params "[["mobile","iot"]]:" 
>   Notice: Array to string conversion

I have noticed the array is not getting converted properly. I have referred the following links, but nothing helped me.

[Stackoverflowlink1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589626/symfony2-3-raw-sql-query-with-in-clause) [Stackoverflowlink2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243022/doctrine-dbal-setparameter-with-array-value) [Doctrinelink1](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#doctrinedbaltypes-conversion)

**Note:** I have used the "PARAM_INT_ARRAY" also. And also I tried "array_values" while passing the array as parameter in the bind statement.

Comment: could you try to rename `:business` bind name to something that probably never used, like `:businessBindValue`

Comment: @Lunin: It's noting to do with that. As I have tried that as well. It will result in the same error, even if I change the name of the bind value.

Answer (score 5):

According to [official documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion), it's because

> The parameter list support only works with Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::executeQuery() and Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::executeUpdate(), NOT with the binding methods of a prepared statement.

so you can bind arrays only using those functions, in your case

```
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery(
    'SELECT bu.ID, bu.BUSINESS_NAME FROM business as bu WHERE bu.ID IN (?)',
    array($business),
    array(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It works like this with named placeholders :

```php
/** @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $conn */
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery(
    'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id IN (:ids)',
    ['ids' => [3, 5, 17, 257, 65537]],
    ['ids' => \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY],
);
```

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing an answer. This is just a note to help you improve your answers. To help future users better understand your answer please provide an explanation with your code block. For example, you could explain why your solution works, or how your approach is different from other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error but due to an other reason: array parameter conversion only works with `?` placeholder but fails with named one (at least with DBAL version 2.13).

The original query was something like this

```php
/** @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $conn */
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery(
    'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id IN (:ids)',  // ❌
    ['ids' => [3, 5, 17, 257, 65537]],
    [\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY],
);
```

and it fails with the very same error « **Warning: Array to string conversion** ».

But it works with `?` placeholder (with [DBAL version 2.13](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.13/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion)):

```php
/** @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $conn */
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery(
    'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id IN (?)',  // ✅
    [[3, 5, 17, 257, 65537]],
    [\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY],
);
```